# Don't understand closures example in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, closures

I'm trying to learn about swift and closures.
I'm stuck on this example.

```
 numbers.map({
    (number: Int) -> Int in
    let result = 3 * number
    return result
 })
```

What is (number: Int) -> Int? Is it a function? Where is it defined?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1

What does the keyword "in" do? The docs say to use "to separate the arguments and return type from the body". I'm not sure I understand this. Why isn't "in" used to separate "let result = 3 * number" from "return result".

Comment: This is also a good introduction to closures in Swift:http://letvargo.mooo.com/a-beginners-guide-to-closures-in-swift/)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A closure is just a function with the parameters moved inside the brackets, with the keyword `in` to separate the parameters from the function body. The two following examples define equivalent functions:

```
func myFunc(number: Int) -> Int {
    let result = 3 * number
    return result
}

let myClosure = { (number: Int) -> Int in
    let result = 3 * number
    return result
}
```

You can actually call them both in exactly the same way:

```
let x = myFunc(2)       // x == 6
let y = myClosure(2)    // y == 6
```

Notice how the second example is exactly the same as the first, only in the first example, the parameters `(number: Int) -> Int` are outside the brackets, and in the second example the parameters are inside the brackets, followed by the keyword `in`.

`map` works by taking an array (`numbers`, in your example) and creating a new array that is the result of applying the closure function to each element in `numbers`. So if `numbers` is `[1, 2, 3]`, the example above will start with `1`. It will apply the closure function which will produce a `3` (cuz all it does is multiply the element from the first array by 3). It does that for each element in `numbers`, until it has produced a new array, `[3, 6, 9]`.

If you wanted to, you could call `map` using the names of either the above function or the above closure, or by writing it out explicitly inside of `map`. All of the below examples are totally equivalent:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]

// Example 1
let times3 = numbers.map(myFunc)        // times3 == [3, 6, 9]

// Example 2
let timesThree = numbers.map(myClosure) // timesThree == [3, 6, 9]

// Example 3
let xThree = numbers.map({ (number: Int) -> Int in
    let result = 3 * number
    return result                       // xThree == [3, 6, 9]
})
```

Note that Example 3 is the same as Example 2, only in Example 3 the closure is spelled out explicitly inside of `map`, whereas in Example 2 the closure has been assigned to a constant called `myClosure`, and the constant has been supplied to `map`.

Hope this helps - closures are fun, but confusing.

Comment: i am also stuck with closures, but your answer help me to understand.Thanks you.

Comment: Hey thanks Roman, this surely did help. It's now very clear to me. Apple's explanation was a bit too steep to get on the first try.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped me to understand how this code snippet works.

Comment: @Roman Sausarnes Thank you so much for making it for Layman, sir I would request kindly explain $0, $1 used in Closure.

Answer (score 2):

The function you're calling takes a closure as its parameter:

```
numbers.map({...})
```

The closure provided to the function is expected to receive a parameter when it is executed by the function you called. This parameter is defined in your closure:

```
  (number: Int) -> Int in
```

You may now use the parameter *in* the contents of the closure

```
  let result = 3 * number
  return result
```

Answer (score 0):

*Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used in your code.*

**Syntax:**

```
{(parameterName: ParameterType) -> returnType in
    //Statements
}
```

*Practical Scenario: When user want to apply filter and want to select values which is more than 300(in this case) we can use closures to achive this.*

```
var elements: [Int] = [Int]() //Declaring Empty array
elements = [1001, 999, 555, 786, 988, 322, 433, 128, 233, 222, 201, 276, 133]

var filteredElements = elements.map({(num: Int) -> Int? in
    return num > 300 ? num : nil
})

output:
[Optional(1001), Optional(999), Optional(555), Optional(786), Optional(988), Optional(322), Optional(433), nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

*From Below code you can clearly see we are passing closure to elements.map() function.*

**Closure:**

```
{(num: Int) -> Int? in
        return num > 300 ? num : nil
    }
```

*`(num:Int)` is parameter.*
*Int? is we are going to return Optional Integer Type.*

*After `in` we can write your logic.*

You can read more about closure [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).